# Prove that there exist infinitely many $n$ such that $d(n+1)>d(n)$, where $d(n)$ is number of positive factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

> Prove that there exist infinitely many $n$ such that $d(n+1)>d(n)$, where $d(n)$ is number of positive factors of $n$.

I have think of using proof by contradiction, by setting a largest integer $k$ such that $d(k+1)>d(k)$. Does anyone has any idea or hints?

Comment: Can you use the fact that there are infinitely many primes?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't think so....

Comment: Well, if $n$ is prime then $n+1$ is not prime.  So $d(n) = 2$ and $d(n+1) > 2$.  So as there are infinitely "special cases" where $d(n) = 2$ and $d(n+1) > 2$, there are infinitely "general cases" where $d(n+1) > d(n)$.  So, yes, you *can* use the fact that there are infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 1):

The number of divisors of $2^n$ is $n+1$, so the number of divisors can become arbitary large. If from some point on , $d(n+1)\le d(n)$ would always hold, the number of divisors would be bounded for all positive integers. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

> I have think of using proof by contradiction, by setting a largest integer $k$ such that $d(k+1)>d(k)$.

This approach is good, and will work. Let's continue it. So $k$ is the largest integer such that $d(k+1) > d(k)$. What does that mean about $d(k+1)$, $d(k+2)$, $d(k+3)$, and so on? Well, it means that

- $d(k+2)$ is NOT larger than $d(k+1)$, that is, $d(k+2) \le d(k+1)$;
- $d(k+3)$ is NOT larger than $d(k+2)$, that is, $d(k+3) \le d(k+2)$;

and so on. So we conclude that
$$
d(k+1) \ge d(k+2) \ge d(k+3) \ge d(k+4) \ge d(k+5) \ge \cdots
$$
and so on.

What this means is that $d(n)$ is "weakly decreasing" for $n > k$, or in simpler terms, $d(n)$ never gets larger than $d(k)$.

So to get a contradiction, we should come up with some $n$ such that $d(n)$ keeps getting larger and larger. Peter's answer gives one idea: $n$ is a power of two $(n = 2^m$). Another idea would be to consider
$$
n = p_1 p_2 p_3 \ldots p_m,
$$
the product of the first $m$ prime numbers.